# Unhandled stream error in pipe for spawned NodeJS process on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, ssh, stream

guys! I am trying build own git server under NodeJS. With http all works just fine, but I have stuck in problem with pipes during **push** in ssh2 session.

```
client.on('session', (accept, reject) => {
    accept()
       .on('exec', (accept, reject, info) => {
            let channel = accept(),
            command = info.command,
            regexp = /git-(upload|receive)-pack\'\/(.*?).git\'$/,
            matches = command.match(regexp);

            //.. some code
            //.. command looks like 'git-receive-pack /Users/mykhailobielan/projects/git_server/repos/06565f90-9e22-11e7-94e7-815f98a3fa17.git'

            command = command.split(' ');
            var child = spawn(command.shift(), command);
            child.stdout.pipe(channel);
            channel.pipe(child.stdin);
            channel.on('close', (code) => channel.exit(0));

            channel.on('error', (code) => channel.exit(1));
            child.stdout.on('error', (data) => channel.exit(1));
            child.stdin.on('error', (data) => channel.exit(1));

            child.stdout.on('data', (data) => channel.exit(0));
        });
});
```

When I add last line ***child.stdout.on('data', (data) => channel.exit(0))*** all works on Ubuntu but fails on Mac OS X with error:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 280 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: internal/streams/legacy.js:59
remote:       throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
remote:       ^
remote: 
remote: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32590
remote:     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
remote:     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
remote:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
To ssh://localhost:3333/mike/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://mike@localhost:3333/mike/project.git'
```

without this line user get error on both systems (without error explanation on Ubuntu).

As I understand this error occurs when there is no error handler on stream, but they exists and I can't debug internal code...

So, what is this error about and why is it always occur?

Comment: Sending an exit code when you receive a chunk of stdout data does not seem correct. You should *instead* call `channel.exit(x)` on `child.on('exit', ...)` and `channel.close()` on `child.on('close', ...)`.

Comment: As far as the error goes, it looks like you're trying to make some TCP (HTTP or otherwise) connection from the server and it's failing.

Comment: @mscdex, I know It looks strange, but it works correctly (couse of no data to lose in stdout stream, I think). 
I tried with `close` and `exit` events on spawned process but It still doesn't work (same error)...